# Excel, rearrange and match rows in one table so that it matches another table

Tags: microsoft-excel, rearrange

I have two tables in Excel where the number of rows differ.
The second column in each table displays a percentage.

For example, **ID(N)** (6.7%) + **ID(C)** (2.8%) in Table 1

matches

the percentage of **Person(E)** (9.5%) in Table 2.

Is there a way to rearrange and combine some IDs of Table 1 so that the number of rows equals 14 and the percentages match the distribution of those in Table 2?

1. Table 1 with 26 rows

[image: Table 1 with 26 rows]

2. Table 2 with 14 rows

[image: Table 2 with 14 rows]

Comment: Describe the algorithm you are using to accomplish this task. Then we can help you implement it in Excel.

Comment: where is the "(2.8%)" in Table 1 ?